# Draw something outside of the plot, between the axis and plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some generic plot with continuous X and categorical Y axis, for example:

```
data(iris)
p1 <-
  ggplot(iris, aes(y=Species, x=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_violin()
```

[image: p1]

Now I want to annotate it with some labels that should be positioned right next to the Y axis, with a quick-and-dirty solution like this:

```
df.labels <- data.frame(Species=c('setosa','versicolor','virginica'), Labels=c('labA','labB','labC'))

p2 <- p1 + geom_text(data = df.labels, aes(x=4, y=Species, label=Labels))
```

[image: p2]

Note that I had to indicate `x=4` explicitly; for more general case I made this function:

```
add_label <- function(inpPlot, inpData, colLabel){
  plotX1 <- ggplot_build(inpPlot)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range[1]
  plotX2 <- ggplot_build(inpPlot)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range[2]
  plotW <- plotX2 - plotX1
  posX <- plotX1 - 0.05*plotW

  colGrp <- as_label(inpPlot$mapping$y)
    
  inpPlot + 
    coord_cartesian(clip='off') +
    geom_text(data = inpData, aes_string(x='posX', y=colGrp, label=colLabel))  
}

p3 <- add_label(p1, df.labels, 'Labels')
```

[image: p3]

What I don't like in this solution:

1. Offset calculated as "5% of plot width" doesn't work very well when I resize plot window (I would like to have a fixed absolute distance between the axis and the labels)
2. It doesn't work if my initial plot has `coord_cartesian()` applied, for example:

```
p1c <- p1 + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(5,NA))
p4 <- add_label(p1c, df.labels, 'Labels')
```

[image: p4]

3. Labels are shown on the plot area itself, I want them to be outside of the plot area (but "inside" from the Y axis, i.e. to the right from the axis labels).
4. What I would like to have ideally, is something like this:

   `p5 <- add_label_good(p1c, df.labels, 'Labels')`

[image: p5]
i.e. it should draw labels between the axis and plot area, and this space should be of fixed width.
Is there any way at all to achieve this?

Comment: The obvious solution is to use facet strips (these can easily be modified so that the facets look like a single panel). Or do you need to maintain the option to use facets?

Comment: hmmm I didn't know about drawing on facet strips, can you give an example or keywords to search? Yes, ideally I would like to save that option because I do use `facet_wrap()` sometimes, but if I don't get a better solution it would be a good workaround!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use facet strips:

```r
p1 + facet_grid(Species~., scales = 'free_y', switch = "y",
                labeller = labeller(Species = function(x) {
                  df.labels$Labels[match(x, df.labels$Species)]})) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0, face =  "bold",
                                         margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10)),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"))
```

[image]

Another option is to use `ggtext::element_markdown()` and use the axis text itself as a label:

```r
p1 +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = function(x) {
    paste(x, df.labels$Labels[match(x, df.labels$Species)],
          sep = paste0(rep("&nbsp; ", 5), "<b>", collapse = ""))
  }) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]

For a truly fixed-width text area on the far left of the plot, you could use `annotation_custom`

```r
p1 + 
  annotation_custom(grid::rectGrob(x = unit(10, "mm"), y = 0.5,
                                   width = unit(20, "mm"), height = 1,
                                   gp = grid::gpar(col = NA))) +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob(df.labels$Labels,
                    x = unit(10, "mm"),
                    y = c(0.81, 0.5, 0.19)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might consider `patchwork`, with two aligned plots:

```
library(patchwork)

plot_labels <-  ggplot(df.labels, aes(x = 0, y = Species, label = Labels)) +
  geom_text(hjust = 0) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, margin = margin(0,12,0,0, unit = "pt")))

plot_labels +
  (p1 + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
              axis.text.y = element_blank())) +
  plot_layout(widths = c(1,8))
```

[image]

Comment: that's cool! Though there's still a small issue with resizing: `widths` in the `plot_layout()` are relative, so if the plot width is large, there's a lot of empty space in the left area, I would prefer it to stay fixed. But that's really minor thing, otherwise looks great!

Comment: (I will keep the question open for a little more just to see if there are more solutions)